# How do you use the Fluid paginate widget for a menu?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

I have a site package that has a custom menu, and I want to be able to use the Fluid pagination widget on the menu items.

I set it up as described in the documentaion, and it shows the correct number of items with some page links. However those page links do not work and it will only ever show the first set of items.

How can I get the pagination links to work?

Fluid template:

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{menuItems}" as="items" configuration="{settings.paginate}">
  <f:for each="{items}" as="item">
    ...
  </f:for>
</f:widget.paginate>
```

The pagination generates links that look like this:

```
?id=15&tx_mysite[%40widget_0][currentPage]=2
```

Comment: what do you mean the links dont work? If you click on the next link or any number in the pagination, will it return a white page? Are these {menuItems} a result of a search?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas The link reloads the page with a query string at the end as you would expect, but the items will always be page 1. The `{menuItems}` is just an array of items from my menu element.

Comment: where are the items coming from? Your controller?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas My custom content element using the pages field and a `MenuProcessor`. This all works fine. The links from the pagination widget are incorrect somehow. I've added an example of the link above.